# Sorting & grouping an array

Tags: algorithm

Suppose an array

```
[["A", "", "B", "", ""],
["B", "D", "", "", ""],
["", "C", "", "D", "A"],
["A","","","K",""]]
```

The output should be:

```
[["A","","","","A"],
["B","","","",""],
["","D","","D",""],
["","C","","",""],
["A","","","",""],
["","","","K",""]]
```

That is, same values should be grouped together, duplicates and order (as encountered) should be preserved. Is there any algorithm for this?

Comment: The question doesn't seem clear. If you're grouping A's in the first line, why is there another line containing A in the output?

Comment: And why there is not a B in third position in the second line?

Comment: And finally regarding your question at the end, if you can describe to another person how to get from an aribtrary input to a correct output step by step, then there is an algorithm. You've just created it.